# How can I kill Finder if it's not responding?

Tags: finder

I have some Finder windows that I just cannot close. They are completely unresponsive, and have the rainbow wheel whenever I select any of them.

Force Quit / Relaunch doesn't help, because the windows just get reopened again and they continue to be unresponsive. They also don't respond to e.g. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>.

Other applications are fine, it's just Finder that's stuck.

Is there a way I can force quit Finder without reopening all the windows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5703354).

Open a terminal, and move the saved settings from Finder into a backup folder just in case:

```
mv ~/L*/S*/*finder.savedState Desktop
```

Then, you can Force Quit Finder as usual using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or use this handy terminal command:

```
killall Finder
```

Then, assuming everything looks good, you can delete the `finder.savedState` folder which has appeared on your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

You can relaunch the Finder.
Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> and right click on the Finder icon on the Dock. Then select `Relaunch` and it's done.

Comment: Relaunch in general didn't work - it opened all the unresponsive windows again which kept rainbow-wheeling. control + alt + right-click is a handy shortcut though!